# Issue comparing to strings in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

I need to make a bash script to compare the space of a vg on redhat servers.
What I have so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash

##VARS
CMD=$(vgs | grep vgSoft | awk -F" " '{print $7}' | awk -F"<" '{print $2}'| awk -F"g" '{print $1}')
SPACE="10.00"

if [[ "$CMD" < "$SPACE" ]]; then
    echo "It's not enough space, you must extend the VG"
    echo "Space is equal to: $CMD GB"
elif [[ "$CMD" == "$SPACE" ]]; then
    echo "It's enough space but consider extend the VG"
elif [[ "$CMD" > "$SPACE" ]]; then
    echo "It's enough space"
    echo "Space is equal to: $CMD GB"
fi
```

What do I do with this command is obtaing the output of volume groups and parse the data for obtain the desired value `vgs | grep vgSoft | awk -F" " '{print $7}' | awk -F"<" '{print $2}'| awk -F"g" '{print $1}'` and save it to the CMD variable.
Where the output of `vgs` command is:

```
[root@server~]# vgs
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  vgSoft   2  13   0 wz--n-  71.99g <26.14g
  vgSys    1  12   0 wz--n- <63.51g <36.52g
```

So in this case, the result of my CMD variable is **26.14**
And I'm making the comparison with the value 10.00 (which is assigned to the SPACE variable).

But I'm having an issue comparing the strings, because is the output of `vgs` command is for example 9.46 the script says me that **"It's enough space"** when the output should be **"It's not enough space, you must extend the VG"**.
As far I remember I don't be able to use the operators "eq" "gt" "ne" because I'm comparing to strings and not integer values.

Comment: Bash only supports integers, you can't compare numbers with decimals.

Comment: `<` and `>` are for string comparisons, not numeric. Use `-lt` and `-gt` for numbers.

Comment: You shouldn't use string comparison when comparing numbers. `2 < 10` is false when doing string comparison.

Comment: The string 9.46 is bigger than the string 10.00 because 9 is   greater than 1, lexicographically speaking.

Comment: Why not? Likewise, I am treating the data as a string and not as a number precisely because a data of type integer cannot have decimals. 
But I'll try @Barmar

Comment: Use a shell like zsh or ksh that supports floating point math, or a different tool completely to do the comparison. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022 has examples

Comment: For example, you can do it all in a single awk instance.

Comment: You're already using awk. Go ahead and improve it so it does what you want and also so it's only executed once.

Comment: As an aside, check [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) and [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) where you also have the dubious honor of a useless `awk | awk`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. We can do all this in single `awk`.

We have an `awk` variable named `space` where I have defined value as `10` as per shown attempts of OP, one could change it as per need.

```
vgs | awk -v space="10" '
FNR==1 || !/vgSoft/{ next }
{
  value=substr($7,2,length($7)-1)+0
}
value<space { 
  print "It\047s not enough space, you must extend the VG"
  next
}
value==space{
  print "It\047s enough space but consider extend the VG"
  next
}
value>space {
  print "It\047s enough space"
}
'
```

***OR*** in case you have 7th field in lines which could OR couldn't have starting `<` in its value so to deal with these kind of situations please try following `awk` code.

```
vgs | awk -v space="10" '
FNR==1 || !/vgSoft/{ next }
{
  sub(/^</,"",$7)
  value=$7+0
}
value<space { 
  print "It\047s not enough space, you must extend the VG"
  next
}
value==space{
  print "It\047s enough space but consider extend the VG"
  next
}
value>space {
  print "It\047s enough space"
}
'
```

***Explanation:*** Running `vgs` command first and sending its standard output as a standard input to `awk` program. In `awk` program creating variable `space` with value of 10 as per shown attempts. Then in main program, checking condition(s) if its line first line OR line does not contain `vgSoft` string then simply jump to next line. If a line contains `vgSoft` string then creating a variable named `value` which will have value from 7th field of current line(without `<` and `g` from 7th field), then using 3 conditions to check(if value is equal to OR lesser than OR grater than space or not) accordingly printing statements then.

Fair warning I don't have vgs command with me so I tested this code with putting your sample output of `vgs` command into an Input_file and running it against `awk` program and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for this and for the clearly explanation! It was very helpful and I was able to solve my problem.
I didn't know that AWK is so powerful.

Comment: Just to ask, if in some cases it had "<" and in others it didn't, how could it be done?

Comment: @FedeBerbara, I have added OR solution now, which will handle lines whose 7th fields are either starting from `<` or not it will take care of both cases. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You may just use the echo command in combination with bc for comparison as shown below

```
$ SPACE=10.00
$ CMD=9.46
$ echo "${CMD}>${SPACE}" | bc
0
$ CMD=10.46
$ echo "${CMD}>${SPACE}" | bc
1
```

Comment: It's a good idea, I'm going to test because I don't know if BC is installed on all servers or is a package that comes by default in redhat

Answer (score 0):

Doing it in just `awk`:

```sh
vgs | awk -v space=10.00 '/vgSoft/ {
   free = substr($7, 2, length($7) - 2)+0 # Assumes the < and g will always be there
   if (free < space) {
     print "It'"'"'s not enough space, you must extend the VG"
     print "Space is equal to: " space " GB"
   } else if (free == space) {
     print "It'"'"'s enough space but consider extend the VG"
   } else {
     print "It'"'"'s enough space"
     print "Space is equal to: " space " GB"
   }
   exit
}'
```

Comment: The ugly `'"'"'` stuff is for getting single quotes into the output strings without breaking shell quoting.

Comment: Thanks for this as I told to RavinderSingh13! It was very helpful and I was able to solve my problem.
I didn't know that AWK is so powerful, I should read more about it

Comment: What if in some cases I have <and in others I don't?

Comment: @FedeBerbara Then your sample data should include such cases, and the way to extract the number depends on if you want to use GNU awk or generic POSIX awk.